# How do I impose a condition that must be satisfied by *any two* members of a set?

Tags: python, set, quantifiers

I want to use python to define one set in terms of another, as follows: For some set N that consists of sets, define C as the set such that an element n of N is in C just in case *any two* elements of n both satisfy some specific condition.

Here is the particular problem I need to solve. Consider the power set N of the set of ordered pairs of elements in x={1,2,3,4,5,6}, and the following subsets of N:

i = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,4},{4,3},{5,6},{6,5}}

j = {{3,3},{4,4},{1,2},{2,1},{5,6},{6,5}}

k = {{5,5},{6,6},{1,2},{2,1},{3,4},{4,3}}

Using python, I want to define a special class of subsets of N: the subsets of N such that any two of their members are both either in i, j, or k.

More explicitly, I want to define the set terms: C = {n in N| for all a, b in n, either a and b are both in i or a and b are both in j or a and b are both in k}.

I'm attaching what I tried to do in Python. But this doesn't give me the right result: the set C I'm defining here is not such that any two of its members are both either in i, j, or k.

Any leads would be much appreciated!

```
import itertools

def powerset(iterable):

    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]


ordered_pairs = [[j,k] for j in x for k in x if k>=j]

powers = list(powerset(ordered_pairs))

i = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,4],[4,3],[5,6],[6,5]]
j = [[3,3],[4,4],[1,2],[2,1],[5,6],[6,5]]
k = [[5,5],[6,6],[1,2],[2,1],[3,4],[4,3]]

M = [i,j,k]

C = []

for n in powers:
    for a in n: 
        for b in n:
            for m in M:
                if a in m:
                    if b in m:
                        if a != b:
                            C.append(n)
                        if len(n) == 1:
                            C.append(n)
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: C should have elements like [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] in it. (I don't want to give it as an output, but use it to define something else that I can then give as output.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that the ordered pairs you list are sets, not pairs.  Use tuples, since they're hashable, and you'll be able to easily generate the power set using `itertools`.  With that done, you have an easier time identifying the qualifying subsets.

The code below implements that much of the process.  You can accumulate the hits at the `HIT` line of code.  Even better, you can collapse the loop into a nested comprehension using `any` to iterate over the three `zone` sets.

```
test_list = [
    set(((1,1),(2,2))),                     # trivial hit on i
    set(),                                  # trivial miss
    set(((1, 1), (4, 4), (6, 6))),          # one element in each target set
    set(((3, 3), (6, 2), (4, 4), (2, 2))),  # two elements in j
]

i = set(((1,1),(2,2),(3,4),(4,3),(5,6),(6,5)))
j = set(((3,3),(4,4),(1,2),(2,1),(5,6),(6,5)))
k = set(((5,5),(6,6),(1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(4,3)))

zone = [i, j, k]

for candidate in test_list:
    for target in zone:
        overlap = candidate.intersection(target)    
        if len(overlap) >= 2:
            print("HIT", candidate, target)
            break
    else:
        print("MISS", candidate)
```

Output:

```
HIT {(1, 1), (2, 2)} {(5, 6), (4, 3), (2, 2), (3, 4), (1, 1), (6, 5)}
MISS set()
MISS {(4, 4), (1, 1), (6, 6)}
HIT {(6, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (2, 2)} {(1, 2), (3, 3), (5, 6), (4, 4), (2, 1), (6, 5)}
```